# In SQL Server, remove everything between two strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, I have a table with a column that includes different ways of quoted text. I try to find a way during `select` to remove those quotes and keep the original text only.

This is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8605/1)

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTexts
    ([text] varchar(max))
;

INSERT INTO ExampleTexts
    ([text])
VALUES
    ('[q]This is a quote[/q]Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
    ('[q attribute]This is a quote with an attribute [/q]Full-featured access management'),
    ('[q]This is a quote[/q]Robust LDAP server [q]This is another quote[/q] for Java'),
    ('[q]This is a quote [q]This is another quote[/q][/q]Robust LDAP server for Java'),
    ('This is a text, but guess, without a quote'),
    ('Maybe we have this [q] but without the ending tag')
;
```

As you can see, a quote always starts with `[q` and always end with `[/q]`. I can have one or more quotes in a field. Quotes with attributes like `[q attribute]`, nested quotes, or even false alarms with a starting tag but not an ending tag.

The desired output from the above is

```
|                                                                               text |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                            Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions |
|                                                    Full-featured access management |
|                                                        Robust LDAP server for Java |
|                                                        Robust LDAP server for Java |
|                                         This is a text, but guess, without a quote |
|                                  Maybe we have this [q] but without the ending tag |
```

I tried the following solutions, but neither of them can handle all the cases

```
SELECT case when charindex('q]',text) > 0 then right (text, (len(text)- charindex('q]',text) - 1)) else text end FROM ExampleTexts

SELECT Replace(Replace(text, '[q', ''), '/q]', '') FROM ExampleTexts
```

Comment: If you can have multiple quotes, you'd have to do this recursively. Personally, I suggest doing this in a different language that supports Regex replacement, or implement a CLR function on your instance that does Regex replacement. *And also update that instance; 2008 has been completely unsupported for over 18 months.*

Comment: I do this at the moment in Python where I get all the data from the SQL and run a script to clean them. But I find it time consuming when I have to do it regularly. So I am looking for something that I can integrate in my SQL query. About the update, it's not my call to do it, but I am aware of it. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: Then I would look into getting some Regex CLR functions on  your instance for Regex operations; though you might struggle to find ones that support 2008 now.

Comment: What is this, poor man's XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ClearQuotes (
    @text varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE
        @o_tag varchar(2) = '[q',
        @c_tag varchar(4) = '[/q]'

    DECLARE
        @o int = CHARINDEX( @o_tag, @text ),
        @c int = CHARINDEX( @c_tag, @text ),
        @b bit = 0,
        @x varchar(MAX);

    WHILE @o > 0 AND @c > 0 BEGIN

        -- Get the quoted segment.
        SET @x = SUBSTRING ( @text, @o, @c - @o + LEN ( @c_tag ) );

        -- Set the nested-quote bit flag to false.
        SET @b = 0;

        -- Look for a nested quote.
        IF CHARINDEX ( @o_tag, @x, LEN ( @o_tag ) ) > 0
            SET @b = 1;

        WHILE @b = 1 BEGIN

            -- Get the next open tag position.
            SET @o = CHARINDEX ( @o_tag, @text, @o + LEN ( @o_tag ) );
            SET @x = SUBSTRING ( @text, @o, @c - @o + LEN ( @c_tag ) );

            IF CHARINDEX ( @o_tag, @x, LEN ( @o_tag ) ) = 0
                SET @b = 0;

        END

        -- Remove the unwanted quote.
        SET @text = STUFF ( @text, @o, @c - @o + LEN ( @c_tag ), '' );

        -- Check again.
        SELECT
            @o = CHARINDEX( @o_tag, @text ),
            @c = CHARINDEX( @c_tag, @text );

    END

    RETURN LTRIM ( RTRIM ( @text ) );

END
GO
```

Here are the results against your sample dataset:

```
DECLARE @ExampleTexts table ( [text] varchar(MAX) );
INSERT INTO @ExampleTexts VALUES
    ('[q]This is a quote[/q]Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions')
    , ('[q attribute]This is a quote with an attribute [/q]Full-featured access management')
    , ('[q]This is a quote[/q]Robust LDAP server [q]This is another quote[/q] for Java')
    , ('[q]This is a quote [q]This is another quote[/q][/q]Robust LDAP server for Java')
    , ('This is a text, but guess, without a quote')
    , ('Maybe we have this [q] but without the ending tag');

SELECT
    dbo.ClearQuotes ( [text] ) AS cleaned_text
FROM @ExampleTexts;
```

Returns

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                      cleaned_text                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions |
| Full-featured access management                         |
| Robust LDAP server  for Java                            |
| Robust LDAP server for Java                             |
| This is a text, but guess, without a quote              |
| Maybe we have this [q] but without the ending tag       |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```